# Product of Gamma by Beta rv

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, gamma-distribution, beta-distribution

If $X$ has a beta distribution $ \beta(\alpha,b)$, $Y$ has a gamma distribution $\Gamma (K,\theta)$ and $X$ is independent of $Y$. What is the distribution of the product $P=XY$ .

Thanks!

Comment: The PDF can be obtained as a linear combination of confluent hypergeometric functions.  If that form is not useful to you, then please edit your question to include a description of what you need to know about the product distribution.

Comment: Could you please provide me with some references?(I need the PDF or the MGF of this product)

Comment: Brute-force application of a [formula for the ratio PDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution#Derivation) will do it.

Comment: @whuber  if you please, I need the detailed calculation (it's complicated..)

Comment: Actually, it looks pretty simple: expand the integrand $f_X(x)f_Y(z/x)/x$ as a Maclaurin series in $z$ and integrate term-by-term from $0$ to $1$. The result clearly follows the pattern of development of hypergeometric functions, so it remains only to determine their parameters, which can be done by inspection.

Comment: @whuber  very good! now I am trying to calculate the MGF; Any hint ?

Comment: I made no headway trying to compute the integral for the mgf. Perhaps a study of Laplace (or Fourier) transforms of confluent hypergeometric functions would provide an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given:

- $X \sim \text{Beta}(a,b)$ with pdf $f(x)$:

[image]

- $Y \sim \text{Gamma}(k,\theta)$ with pdf $g(y)$:

[image]

**Solution:** Then, the pdf of the product $Z = X Y$ can be automatically derived via:

[image]

where I am using the `TransformProduct` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*, and where `Hypergeometric1F1` denotes the Kummer confluent hypergeometric function:  http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Hypergeometric1F1.html

This formulation works nicely, except for certain combinations of integer values of the parameters (indeterminate - please see discussion below). [If say $a = 4$ and $k = 3$, just enter $k$ as 3.0000001 and it will side-step the issue.]

**Quick Monte Carlo check**

It is always a good idea to check symbolic solutions with Monte Carlo methods. Here is a quick comparison of the exact theoretical solution derived above (dashed RED curve) against an empirical Monte Carlo simulation of the pdf of the product (squiggly BLUE), when ${a = 3, b = 6, k = 2.2, \theta = 5}$

[image]

All done.

Comment: +1 The reason you run into trouble for certain values of the parameters is that Gamma has poles where $a-k$ and $a+b-k$ are negative integers and the hypergeometric functions have corresponding poles and zeros to cancel them, leading to finite values. You can sneak up to the correct value by taking limits (which *Mathematica* will do); they will involve derivatives of the confluent hypergeometric function with respect to its parameters (the first two arguments).

Comment: @whuber Many thanks -> _Mathematica_ spat out the condition $a>k$. However, the problem with integer-valued $k$ occurs even when $a > k$;  moreover, the condition $a>k$ appeared superfluous [checked with Monte Carlo].

Comment: It's not superfluous; in fact, it's not enough. If (a) any of the Gamma arguments $a+b-k$ or $k-a$ or $a-k$ are negative integers or (b) any of the second arguments of the hypergeometric function $1-k+a$ and $1+k-a$ are non-positive integers, the result is indeterminate. That leaves only the possibility $k=a$ when $k$ and $a$ are integral!

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. Still, the condition $a>k$ is superfluous or too general, when the required constraint is that: either $a$ or $k$ must not be an integer, or similar.

Answer (score 1):

This distribution is called the *Gamma-Inverse Beta* distribution in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bjps/1333632164). It is available in the R package `brr`.

```
nsims <- 1e6
alpha <- 3
beta <- 5
K <- 6
theta <- 4
sims <- rgamma(nsims, shape = K, rate = theta) * rbeta(nsims, alpha, beta)

plot(density(sims, to=3))
curve(brr::dGIB(x, K, beta, alpha, theta), # note that alpha and beta are swapped
      add = TRUE, col = "red", lwd = 2, lty = "dashed")
```

[image]

Here is its density function:

```
> brr::dGIB
function (x, a, alpha, beta, rho) 
{
    exp(lnpoch(beta, alpha) - lngamma(a)) * rho^a * x^(a - 1) * 
        exp(-rho * x) * hyperg_U(alpha, a - beta + 1, rho * x)
}
```

$$
\frac{{(\beta)}_\alpha}{\Gamma(a)}\rho^a x^{a-1} \exp(-\rho x) U(\alpha, a-\beta+1, \rho x), \qquad x > 0
$$
where $U$ is the Tricomi hypergeometric function.

There's a generalization of this distribution to random matrices. It is a *type II confluent hypergeometric function distribution of kind two* (see Gupta & Nagar's book *Matrix variate distributions*).

```
library(matrixsampling)
sims2 <- rmatrixCHIIkind2(20000, nu = K, alpha = beta, 
                          beta = K+1-alpha, theta = 1/theta, p = 1)
lines(density(sims2, to=3), col = "orange", lwd = 2, lty = "dashed")
```

[image]

The *mgf* is given in Gupta & Nagar's book. With your notations, this gives
$$
\textrm{mgf}(t) = {}_2\!F_1(\alpha, K, \alpha+\beta, t/\theta).
$$

```
library(gsl)
hyperg_2F1(alpha, K, beta+alpha, 0.2/theta)
## [1] 1.121871
mean(exp(0.2*sims))
## [1] 1.121846
```