# Best distribution to model fuel loss

Tags: distributions, sampling

I'm trying to simulate the process of losing fuel (through driving).

Currently people start of with $100\%$ of fuel, and loses $x\%$ of fuel everyday where $x \sim N(10,5^2)$. However the normal distribution is unsatisfactory because it could return negative numbers and I don't want people to "gain" fuel other than refueling. Is there other distributions that suit my purpose?

Comment: There are any number of distributions that have only non-negative support. Presumably you also don't want anyone to also lose more than 100% as well.

Comment: you are correct.

Comment: Maybe you can model the % loss, for example with a beta distribution?

Comment: You can use Half normal distribution
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution

Comment: Could be realted:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137330/distribution-of-the-product-of-a-gamma-random-variable-and-a-beta-random-variabl

Comment: What do you mean by "loss"?  Is it accidental or uncontrollable release of unused fuel to the environment?  Could it be *usage*? In either case it seems like you need to model "loss" as a function of time, distance, or both: assuming $x$ is modeled as a random variable seems so unrealistic as to be useless.

Comment: By loss I mean losing through driving. I am modeling loss by days, which I now edited my post to reflect that.

Comment: Could you help us interpret what "$x\sim N(10,5^2)$" might mean in terms of losses?  How is that related to fuel as a percentage?  What data, theories, and assumptions are you using for this modeling?  (One cannot validly just make up distributions: they need to have some true relationship with the things you are modeling!) Finally, why do you mention beta distributions in the title?

Comment: Everyday people will drive, which consumes fuel. This fuel consumption, on average, is about 10% of its gas tank, with standard deviation 5. These numbers are currently just random guesses by me.